# Regular expression to find \\[

Tags: php, regex

Trying to find "\[" in my content don't get any results. I use this pattern:

```
preg_replace('/\\\[/', $content, $matches);
```

What's wrong whith my pattern? Thank you.

Update. My fault, I meant `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 6):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) is replacing all found matches. Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) for the first match and [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to get all matches instead:

```
preg_match_all('/\\\[/', $content, $matches);
```

Comment: @Asaph: There is no need to predefine `$matches` since no read access is happening just a write access.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\\\\[/', $content, $matches);
```

Try 4 (four) backslashes, because the pattern you get with three is "\[" which means just "[" to the regexp engine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right one `[\\\\][\[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\\\\\\[`, should work.

Because those two characters have special meaning in regexp they have to be masked like this: `\\\[`. Now when we are putting this regexp into a string for php every backslash has to be masked again because backslash has a special meaning in a string.